# Can I install mobo drivers from a USB and if so how?

Tags: windows-7, usb, installation

I want to reinstall my OS (windows 7 64 bit) but I lost my drivers for my Mobo. Is there a way to put them on a USB jump drive and install them from that after I've formatted my HDD? How can I do this if so?

Comment: Do you mean you are updating your bios? If you are updating drivers then you can just boot into the os and run them from USB.

Comment: What you want to do is possible.  You won't be asked for drivers until your intial boot into Windows.

Comment: Ok thank you. I just meant to install the drivers for the Motherboard. Nothing to do with the BIOS, just the stuff that's necesary to get it running.

Answer (score 0):

Before you format the system or on another system, download all drivers to the USB drive.  Once you install Windows again you can use the USB drive to install/update the drivers.

Answer (score 0):

As another person referred, before formatting download all necessary drivers (or at least SATA/AHCI plus wireless/ethernet) and store them on a USB drive.
Then, proceed accordingly to your needs during the format, using the USB to add the AHCI/sata drivers to your windows installation in case the hard drive(s) are not properly recognized.